# Failed Automatic Update in Windows 10 Fall Creators Update for "Feature Update for version 1709"

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-10-v1709

As strange as the above sounds, after clean-installing version 1709 from my PC, I'm getting two updates. The ARM64 system security update (KB4043961) and a "feature update for version 1709".

I keep getting the 0x80d02002 error since yesterday for the update, and I know that other advice such as stopping and restarting services is not working for me. I also know that I shouldn't need a version 1709 feature update, so this just strikes me as odd all-around.

I know Windows is Windows, but if anyone has any ideas, please suggest!

---

I'm using an IBM Thinkpad x61, Intel T7300 Core Duo Pro processor, 1TB Hybrid SSD-Hard Drive, and 8GB RAM.

Bonus: I have English-US as my primary region and language all across the board (made sure of this by using the Region settings in Control Panel). I also have Japanese and Spanish keyboards. Until I right-clicked on the taskbar and enabled the "touch keyboard button" (*mine has been turned off), the emoji keyboard would not appear. After that, I could turn off the touch keyboard, and the emoji keyboard would still appear. Anyone know why that might be?

History: Before that, it was even stranger. I did an in-place update on my 1703 but it ended up not giving me any Windows Store Apps, including the ones usually built into the computer. This may have a lot to do with the way that the in-place upgrade renames your home folder from  to , but I wasn't willing to mess around with this all and decided a clean install would be better.

Comment: Was the second update installed successfully or did it fail, too? I got error `0x800f081f` for `Feature Update for Windows 10, Version 1709 (6)` and for `KB4043961` - nothing seemed to help (tried `sfc /scannow`, `DISM`, etc.p.p.), I was close to open a question here, too. But then I tried to download the KB-update from Microsoft itself - and the issue vanished when I installed that.

Comment: KB4043961 has nothing to do with ARM, KB4043961 is a patch for 1709.  KB4043961 raises the 1709 build to .19 and is totally relevant for your installation so you should install it

Comment: Both updates failed, indeed with such error code. However, using Ramhound's (and more specifically flolilolilo's) advice, I did a manual update and discovered something interesting. When I updated manually using the ARM64-based system option on https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4043961 I executed the file and it told me that "this installation is not necessary and will not proceed". Then, I tried the "x64-based system" option and it worked. Since that time, I have not received any other update. So perhaps the issue was Windows Automatic Update gave me the wrong file.

Comment: While the above doesn't count for a solution (why isn't DISM or sfc catching this, why is giving me the wrong version of a security update bring up a feature update for a feature version I already am using, etc.)... I suppose it is a functional workaround that could be used in the meanwhile.